# How to convert date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd using carbon on Laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have small laravel project working on date conversion. I have date string that getting from request on format dd/mm/yyyy. Code and result show as below.

```
$request->stockupdate ; 
// dd/mm/yyyy (02/05/2019)
```

Then I try to convert to yyyy-mm-dd using carbon.

```
$_stockupdate= Carbon::parse($request->stockupdate)->format('Y-m-d');
```

I got parse result as below.

```
2019/02/05  // Seem it is 2 Feb 2019 not 5 May 2019.
```

That's wrong, It should be 2019/05/02 instead. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: This happend if you modifiy the attribute in model file. i think you had already written a code in model to change the format and here you again try to format the same attribute. You also try coding $_stockupdate= Carbon::parse($request->getOriginal('stockupdate'))->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: Dear  Prashant Prajapati , thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->stockupdate)->format('Y-m-d')
```

Comment: Dear nakov, This is exactly I want, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

This may be also nice and clean

[Carbon Live Editor](https://try-carbon.herokuapp.com/?hide-output-gutter&output-left-padding=10&theme=tomorrow_night&border=none&radius=4&v-padding=15&input=%24mutable%20%3D%20Carbon%3A%3Anow()%3B%0A%24immutable%20%3D%20CarbonImmutable%3A%3Anow()%3B%0A%24modifiedMutable%20%3D%20%24mutable-%3Eadd(1%2C%20%27day%27)%3B%0A%24modifiedImmutable%20%3D%20CarbonImmutable%3A%3Anow()-%3Eadd(1%2C%20%27day%27)%3B%0A%0Avar_dump(%24modifiedMutable%20%3D%3D%3D%20%24mutable)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20bool(true)%0Avar_dump(%24mutable-%3EisoFormat(%27dddd%20D%27))%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20string(12)%20%22Wednesday%2010%22%0Avar_dump(%24modifiedMutable-%3EisoFormat(%27dddd%20D%27))%3B%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20string(12)%20%22Wednesday%2010%22%0A%2F%2F%20So%20it%20means%20%24mutable%20and%20%24modifiedMutable%20are%20the%20same%20object%0A%2F%2F%20both%20set%20to%20now%20%2B%201%20day.%0Avar_dump(%24modifiedImmutable%20%3D%3D%3D%20%24immutable)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20bool(false)%0Avar_dump(%24immutable-%3EisoFormat(%27dddd%20D%27))%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20string(9)%20%22Tuesday%209%22%0Avar_dump(%24modifiedImmutable-%3EisoFormat(%27dddd%20D%27))%3B%20%20%20%2F%2F%20string(12)%20%22Wednesday%2010%22%0A%2F%2F%20While%20%24immutable%20is%20still%20set%20to%20now%20and%20cannot%20be%20changed%20and%0A%2F%2F%20%24modifiedImmutable%20is%20a%20new%20instance%20created%20from%20%24immutable%0A%2F%2F%20set%20to%20now%20%2B%201%20day.%0A%0A%24mutable%20%3D%20CarbonImmutable%3A%3Anow()-%3EtoMutable()%3B%0Avar_dump(%24mutable-%3EisMutable())%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20bool(true)%0Avar_dump(%24mutable-%3EisImmutable())%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20bool(false)%0A%24immutable%20%3D%20Carbon%3A%3Anow()-%3EtoImmutable()%3B%0Avar_dump(%24immutable-%3EisMutable())%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20bool(false)%0Avar_dump(%24immutable-%3EisImmutable())%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20bool(true)%0A&token=live-editor-116)

```php
// DD    Day (2 Numbers)
// MM    Month (2 Numbers)
// YYYY  Year (4 Numbers)

// Will format to 2021-03-18
Carbon\Carbon::now()->isoFormat('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

---

### Using with a Model

If you use a Model like `$data->expired_at` you need to set the type as a date

add this into your Model File:

```
/**
     * The attributes that should be date.
     *
     * @var array
     */
protected $dates = [
        'expired_at',
    ];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
 $date = str_replace('/', '-', $request->stockupdate);
 $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
 OR
 Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->stockupdate)->format('Y-m-d')
```

Comment: Dear jithesh jose, Thank you.