# Laravel after_or_equal have a problem with certain dates

Tags: laravel, validation

Hello I am entering an estimated_date and a max_date,I am trying to validate that maxdate is not less than estimated_date with this

```
'maxdate' => 'required|after_or_equal:estimated_date',
```

works for all dates with exception: if today is 5 and I mark estimated_date as 6 and maxdate as 20 the error message is thrown that maxdate cannot be earlier than estimated_date

I am using dates in Spanish which are ('d / m / y)

how can I solve that?

Comment: Use the [date_format](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-date-format) rule. Ie: `'date_format:d/m/Y|after_or_equal:estimated_date'`

Comment: It works but it generates an error in this line $t->max_date =Carbon::parse($request->maxdate)->format('Y-d-m'); Could not parse '20/08/2021': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (20/08/2021) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character

Comment: That is another problem of how you cast the date with carbon and it is not related to what you ask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950681/how-to-convert-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-using-carbon-on-laravel

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [date_format](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-date-format) rule for custom dates formats.

By example, if you have the following request data:

```
{
    "estimated_date": "06/08/2021",
    "maxdate": "20/08/2021"
}
```

You could do:

```
$request->validate([
    'estimated_date' => 'date_format:d/m/Y',
    'maxdate' => 'date_format:d/m/Y|after_or_equal:estimated_date'
]);
```